# Oil is slippery; rubber is _____?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

What's the best word (or words) to describe rubber's 'gripping' property that is the opposite of oil's slipperiness?

It's not 'rough', since rubber grips without necessarily being rough.

Comment: *Tacky* / *sticky* / *adhesive*?

Comment: Supple, elastic, pliable, springy, stretchy...

Comment: [rubbery](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/rubbery)

Comment: These words aren't really related to high friction, which is the property of rubber I have in mind.

Comment: _Rubbery_ would have been a valid answer if my question were 'Oil is oily...'.

Comment: Certainly that would be a perfect analogue; but _rubbery_ **is** the only common English word that refers to (some of) the properties of rubber. As for grippiness, that has to do with how the rubber's been processed; some are slippery, some are sticky.

Comment: Rubber is slippery when wet.

Comment: Oil is slippery; rubber is ... *not?*

Comment: Considering @jlovegren's objection that oils is a fluid and makes surfaces slippery because it can shear you can compare rubber to teflon instead which could also be considered slippery. What you are interested in is the amount of friction, independent of the underlying physical mechanisms. Nice question. Btw, "has grip" feels more natural to my (non-native) ears than the uncommon "grippy".

Comment: I vote a new word be created: grippery.

Comment: @ermanen Not always, the bottoms of shoes can be grippy when wet

Comment: @Izkata: It was kind of humor but whatever. It depends on other factors but it is generally true.

Comment: ...rubber is rubbish ;)

Comment: You might want to change the subject to "Teflon is slippery, rubber is ____", as many people have pointed out that oil is a facilitator of slipperyness but is not slippery by itself.

Comment: @MarkLakata, but "teflon" doesn't have quite the same cadence as the original:  roses are red, violets are blue, oil is slippery, rubber grips true.

Comment: In my experience, rock climbers universally refer to climbing slippers as being made of "sticky rubber." As a physicist, I would refer to rubber as "high-friction."

Comment: Rubber with oil on it is very slippery. Also you used the best word right on your question... grippy

Comment: @Joseph Neathawk: Rubber with oil on it is slippery, but rubber is _inherently_ grippy nonetheless. Also, I used the word _gripping_ in the question; not _grippy_.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The "obvious" answer is [**grippy**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/grippy) — the ability to grip a surface well. It is less commonly used than *slippery*, but it is a proper word.

Comment: There are some interesting example usages of this word on the [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/grippy) page.

Comment: It is indeed a proper word. I originally thought not because it's not in my big dictionary. My dictionary's obviously not big enough.

Comment: It's a word, but a rather colloquial one, to my ear.

Comment: So, as opposed to the rhetorical 'slippery' slope, we're dealing with a *grippery* slope? : )

Comment: @Ideogram As far as I know, _grippery_ is not a commonly recognized word.

Comment: I still vote for tacky over grippy. Grippy is not as gripping as tacky...

Comment: @200_success It was only meant as a play of words.

Comment: @McGafter, rubber is not tacky. Rubber definitely is grippy: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=grippy+tire

Comment: @Ideogram - its definitely not a proper word, but _slippy_ is sometimes (regionally) used as a replacement for _slippery_.

Answer (score 18):

As has been mentioned in comments, "sticky"or "adhesive" might fit. But the truth is **rubber isn't naturally sticky or adhesive**. It does have **a high "coefficient of friction"** though.  That's why it isn't slippery. In non-technical terms, we can say **rubber is nonslippery** or  **skid-resistant**.

Comment: _Nonslippery_ sounds a bit cumbersome. Like describing a wet cloth as nondry.

Comment: @EmmaV Not exactly the same.  We have the word "wet" as the opposite for "dry", but there isn't (or at least I couldn't find) a less cumbersome opposite for slippery than nonslippery.

Comment: My skid-resistant pencil eraser...?

Comment: My eraser has six surfaces!

Comment: @EmmaV Ok, you win.

Comment: "non-slip" is also an option

Answer (score 13):

The word *tacky* is used when describing the 'grippiness' of golf grips (which are, as it happens, made of rubber), especially when it comes to the 'stickiness' of the rubber compound, as opposed to the roughness of the surface.

Comment: It seems that the term is used widely in the rubber industry. [link](http://www.arizonachemical.com/en/Markets/Tires-and-Rubber/High-Performance-Tackifiers/) [link](http://www.basf.com/group/corporate/en/literature-document:/Brand+Koresin-Brochure--Koresin+High+Performance+Tackifier+for+the+Rubber+Industry-English.pdf)

Comment: Tacky is the best fit. Funny that this "answer" with Tacky only got 3 upvotes, but the first comment on the question used "tacky" and got 9.

Answer (score 10):

The word *slippery* implies very little friction. You want a word that implies a lot of friction, which creates a "gripping" sensation.

To that effect, I couldn't find any simple, commonly used words. [*Frictive*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/frictive) is one, which literally means "friction-y". CarSmack suggested "rubbery", but "rubber is rubbery" seems redundant.

Comment: Are _frictive_, _frictional_ and _frictious_ proper words? They seem not to be found anywhere other than wiktionary.org.

Comment: *Frictional* is definitely a word (it's used in physics, e.g. a frictional force); *frictive* I've never heard before either.

Comment: @JoeZ. Both frictive and frictional are used in physics. Frictive is just less used than frictional

Comment: @JoeZ.- I like your answer. Seems to be much more original and descriptive than the other answers I have read. Certainly worthy of a higher score and so I add my own.

Answer (score 5):

Comments thusfar (including the OP's) seem to confuse friction with rheology. A slippery substance is one with low viscosity, not a low coefficient of friction. A coating of oil makes surfaces slippery because the oil deforms easily and permanently under small shear (i.e., sliding) stress. Rubber deforms only slightly, then returns to its original shape, so a rubber coating does not makes surfaces slippery. At the molecular level, both rubber and oil cling to many types of surfaces on contact, but the difference in slipperiness has to do with the way that the two substances flow.

You can say that oil is plastic (deforms permanently), while rubber is elastic (restores to original shape). Alternately you can say that rubber is viscous (deforms only slightly), while oil is slippery (shears easily). A less technical term for rubber would be skid- or slip-resistant.

Comment: I was refering to friction. I don't think viscosity and plasticity are relevant. Can a solid have viscosity?

Comment: A solid can have resistance to shear, and that behaves the same way as viscosity.

Comment: Elastic materials like rubbers or thermoplastic elastomers are characterized by their [*durometer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shore_durometer), which is a measure of hardness (as measured by the amount of penetration into the surface of a given probe with a given force).

Comment: We have words to describe opposite subjective sensations for many things; these words need not have any, let alone a 1:1, relationship to the words that describe the underlying physical processes. Compare "hot" and "cold": the words that describe what's really going on in the underlying physics have *zero* relevance to the subjective sensations we use "hot" and "cold" to describe. Ditto with oil and slipperiness: the language describes "lay" experience, which predates and has zero concern for the "real" situation at the molecular level.

Comment: Saying that oil is plastic and rubber is something else would be prone to misinterpretation though because rubber is actually plastic while oil is not (though crude oil/petroleum are used to make plastics).

Comment: @LieRyan To try to clear up that confusion: 'plastic' has multiple, albeit related, senses salient to this context: as an adjective for a permanently deformable substance and as a noun for a formable polymer.  Thus, 'oil is plastic' and 'rubber is plastic' are both true statements — for differing senses of 'plastic'.  The use of petroleum as a feedstock for polymer production just compounds the confusion.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I think that learning has to inform our vocabulary to some extent. if we are talking about a material that is man-made and specially engineered, we should not be surprised if engineers' terminology enters lay speech. the germ theory of disease, for example, at one point had no relevance to lay speech, but now it does (because language users learned and incorporated the knowledge into their vocabulary).

Comment: Describing sensations via words for unseen molecular events that contradict the sensations will never happen. Germ theory is incomparable because it replaced another unseen—miasma theory—and didn't have to compete with direct experiential description words. (Aside, neither oil nor rubber are man-made.)

Answer (score 3):

[Unslippery](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unslippery) is certainly a possibility, but I don't like it.

Commercial products such as deck paints tend to use terms such as "non-slip" and "slip-resistant".

Answer (score 1):

The first word that comes to mind without trying too hard is *chafing*. Perhaps you could also try *abrasive*. While they are not perfect matches for rubber to describe the equivalent of slippery to oil, it is a close match.

Answer (score 1):

Rubber is 'tacky'. I like the word tacky. It's kind of tacky like blue tack or the soles of your 'tekkies' (slang word for running shoes in Afrikaans)...

Comment: 'tacky' is more like 'sticky'. and rubber is not 'sticky'